# Lisp function call syntax

Tags: lisp, syntax-error, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a recursive code to do `x^y` but the problem no mater how I update the code it gives me an error.

The Code:

```
    (defun power(x y) (if(> y 0) (* x (power(x (- y 1)))) (1)))
```

Error:

```
CL-USER 11 : 5 >Power 2 3
Error: Undefined operator X in form (X (- Y 1)).
```

Error:

```
CL-USER 11 : 5 >power(2 3)
Illegal argument in functor position: 2 in (2 3).
```

Answer (score 13):

You're calling the function in the wrong way. In lisps function calls have the form:

```
(f a b c)
```

not

```
f(a b c)
```

You had `(power (x (- y 1)))` in your recursive definition, which in turn had `(x (- y 1))` hence the error: x is not a function.

Use `(power x (- y 1))` so your definition becomes:

```
(defun power (x y)
   (if (> y 0)
      (* x
           (power x (- y 1))) 
      1))
```

and call it as `(power 2 3)`

Comment: Replace `(1)` with `1` in the `else` branch, and it will be correct.

Comment: @TerjeD. well spotted!

Answer (score 6):

To expand slightly on the previous (correct) answer, this version uses some idiomatic functions:

```
(defun power (x y)
  (if (plusp y)
    (* x (power x (1- y)))
    1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use parenthesis for grouping since CL thinks you want to call function x and function 1. Remove the excess like this:

```
 (defun power(x y) 
     (if (> y 0) 
         (* x (power x (- y 1)))
         1))
```

Parenthesis goes on the outside, just as in your function:

```
 (power 2 3) ;==> 8
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write  (X ...) in a Lisp expression, you are asserting that X is a function to be called on the arguments ....

Your problem is you have too many parentheses in your expression.  When you write (power (x ..
you've made this assertion.   Write (power x ...  instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling, among others, this code:

```
(power (x (- y 1)))
```

So `power` is called with `(x (- y 1))` as a parameter. Are you sure you want to call `x` as a function?