# Undefined function error in LISP

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, undefined-function

I am working on a Lisp program that contains code to read in the dimensions of boxes and then sort them from shortest to longest lengths (and set each of these new lengths as new variables).

When I attempt to load my file into the interpreter, I get the following error:

```
*** - EVAL: undefined function NEW-D1
```

I am confused as to why I'd be getting this error because `new-d1` isn't a function, it's a variable for the length of the shortest edge of a given box.

Here's the code where `new-d1` is first initialized and set:

```
(defun get-box ()
  (let ((d1 0) (d2 0) (d3 0) (new-d1 0) (new-d2 0) (new-d3 0))
    (setf d1 (read))
    (setf d2 (read))
    (setf d3 (read))
    (if (= d1 -1)
        (exit)
        (progn
         (setq new-d1 (first  (sort (list d1 d2 d3) #'<)))
         (setq new-d2 (second (sort (list d1 d2 d3) #'<)))
         (setq new-d3 (third  (sort (list d1 d2 d3) #'<)))
         (next-part-of-program (new-d1 new-d2 new-d3))))))
```

How can I change my code so the interpreter knows new-d1 isn't a function and doesn't treat it as such? Thanks for any help!

Edited to add: Next part of program code:

```
(defun next-part-of-program(d1 d2 d3)
    (if (> d2 b)
        (put-on-c-list(d1 c-list))
        (if (> d2 a) and (< d2 c)
            (put-on-b-list (d1 b-list))
            (put-on-a-list (d1 a-list)))))
```

Note: I've initialized a-list, b-list, and c-list earlier as global variables/lists to be added to later.

Thanks again!

Comment: When I run your function, I get a different error: the function `next-part-of-program` is undefined. The symbol `new-d1` is not used as a funtion in the above code. Please update your question with the actual code that produces the error.

Comment: It's possible that you have a `next-part-of-program` function defined, and that's the place where `new-d1` is being called or otherwise used as a function.

Comment: Thanks; I've added in the next function in my code. Is `new-d1` used as a function here or could it be even later in my code, such as in `put-on-a-list`?

Comment: You should learn how to use your Lisp debugger to discover where you are in the evaluation (obtain a "backtrace"). This exercise is futile; eventually we will end up with your entire program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lisp function call syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589920/lisp-function-call-syntax)

Comment: I didn't notice the `(new-d1 ...)` call at all! The Lisp that I used evaluates the function first. If you have `(a (b c))`, and neither `a` nor `b` are functions, then `a` is diagnosed.  Common Lisp implementations can do this in either order: they can evaluate the arguments (left or right) and then look up the function, or they can look up the function, and then evaluate the arguments (left to right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line of `get-box` should be:

```
(next-part-of-program new-d1 new-d2 new-d3)))))
```

You should not have parens around the arguments to `next-part-of-program`

Comment: +1; which will reveal another error: Error: The variable B is unbound.

Comment: In this case, is `variable B` referring to a different variable B earlier in my program or one of the params to `next-part-of-program`?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it a bit shorter:

```
(defun get-box (&aux (d1 (read)) (d2 (read)) (d3 (read)))
  (if (= d1 -1)
      (exit)
    (apply #'next-part-of-program
           (sort (list d1 d2 d3) #'<))))
```